# "Though fully aware that to his well-known interest in psychical things was partly due his presence..". - meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading an old story by A. Blackwood, I am unable to decipher the sentence in bold:

> He had told no fearsome story. He had evaded, indeed, many openings
> expressly made for him, **though fully aware that to his well-known
> interest in psychical things was partly due his presence in the
> week-end party.** “I never have experiences—that way,” he said shortly
> when some one asked him point blank for a tale;

I am confused by the "**to**" preposition as well as the usage of "**due**" - to me, it seems as if there were some words missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an oddly-constructed sentence, but the meaning is

> He was aware that **his presence in the weekend party** (the fact that he had been invited) was partly due **to his well-known interest in psychical things.**

Comment: I pored over this one for at least a minute - *after* having checked Google Books to convince myself it probably wasn't just a typesetting error (it was only after seeing the same "apparently unwanted" preposition in multiple different editions that I made my second attempt to parse the construction). Personally, I think it has nothing to commend it, even if the phrasing *was* presumably intentional.